# GridView with 2 rows and horizontal scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

im trying to achieve something looking like this using a GridView in a Windows Store App project [image]

i can get my items in a single line with horizontal scroll, but i want to have a GridView with 2 rows.

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Margin="22,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource GridViewStyle}" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding UserPhotos}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0,7,10,0">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
```

what should i change/add to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that is not really intuitive and the default behavior is usually vertical for the scrollviewer, here is the solution:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Margin="22,0,0,0"   SelectionMode="None" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="144" Height="144"></Ellipse>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    <GridView.Items>
        <x:String>1</x:String>
        <x:String>2</x:String>
        <x:String>3</x:String>
        <x:String>4</x:String>
        <x:String>5</x:String>
        <x:String>6</x:String>
        <x:String>7</x:String>
        <x:String>8</x:String>
        <x:String>9</x:String>
        <x:String>10</x:String>
        <x:String>11</x:String>
        <x:String>12</x:String>
        <x:String>13</x:String>
        <x:String>14</x:String>
    </GridView.Items>
</GridView>
```

Replace with your template and itemssource as you had

Comment: another doubt, where can i edit the margins between each item?

Comment: nevermind, i managed using this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/887e0d68-c815-4c24-987f-c78afe609858/whats-the-standard-margingap-between-the-gridview-items?forum=winappswithcsharp